# 2011 questions clean up

Tags: support, deleted-questions

As part of cleaning up the site, I'm deleting multiple closed and abandoned questions from 2011 where I think they have no historical significance.

Please review the following list, if there is any question that I've deleted by mistake, point it out in an answer.

**Notes**

- "it's salvageable/can be fixed" is not a good reason to not delete at this point. These questions have been abandoned for a long time. If you think it's salvageable, *fix it by editing first* and then add an answer.
- "migrate this" is also not a good reason -- we simply don't migrate old, possibly answered, closed questions to other sites. *However*, if you think a post would be a great question elsewhere ...ask it again on the new site!
- only high-rep users and owners will be able to see the posts.

**Deleted questions**

- [Do I have to eject my flash drive before removing it?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/4696/96)
- [Was the Fukushima accident caused by a sabotage as opposed to an earthquake?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/5668/96)
- [What is the explanation for the Mentos-Diet Cola fountain?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/7354/96)
- [Are benefit-cost estimates for policies and projects accurate enough to be useful?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/6678/96)
- [Can we see the curvature of earth from the top of world's tallest building?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/5310/96)
- [Does having it in your blood mean you do things better?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/3566/96)
- [Does unplugging your stereo while playing can damage it?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/5442/96)
- [How legitimate are the "support an orphan" organizations?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/3271/96)
- [Was Colonel Sanders racist?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/5676/96)
- [Do budget cuts for police forces typically lead to increased crime rates?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/6519/96)
- [Impact of a nuclear bomb explosion in Earth's core](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/5840/96)
- [Does the CIA own part of Facebook?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/2131/96)
- [Did the US win the Vietnam War in any sense?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/5976/96)
- [Does banning liquids from planes verifiably improve flight safety?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/5375/96)
- [How old are phonetic characters?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/4598/96)
- [Is Colgate suppressing vaccine technology that could prevent tooth decay?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/3300/96)
- [Why is 18 (mostly) considered the age of adulthood?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/1993/96)
- [Do (US) Birth Certificate Bonds exist?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/3811/96)
- [Do people see the same seven colour bands in the rainbow?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/2717/96)
- [Does defragging shorten the life of a computer hard-drive?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/7111/96)
- [Nucleotides on asteroids confirm life was created out of inorganic matter?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/5672/96)
- [Are taxes generally detrimental to jobs?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/5367/96)
- [Are laptop batteries (LiIon and LiPo) capable of being exploded?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/5379/96)
- [Is the custom in some cultures of having to marry your cousin based on religion?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/5772/96)
- [Does a day full of house cleaning chores have any observable benefit to your fitness?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/6388/96)
- [If I eat a black widow spider, will I effectively be bitten?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/3726/96)
- [Is it rational to avoid touching doorknobs, elevator buttons and other public surfaces?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/5789/96)

Answer (score 1):

I don't agree with neither the deletion nor the closure of these questions:

https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2131/does-the-cia-own-part-of-facebook

It has a good answer. It has been closed as too localized, but this question could be like general information. Facebook has billion of users, so they might be interested to know if CIA owns part of Facebook.

https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7111/does-defragging-shorten-the-life-of-a-computer-hard-drive

It is a very good question with a notable claim. It has been closed because "claims that are not widely heard or read are off-topic", huh? I've heard this claim thousands of times. Note also that it has a good answer which shows a publication by Google.

Also, this question is on-topic and answered, wondering why it got purged:

https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5310/can-we-see-the-curvature-of-earth-from-the-top-of-worlds-tallest-building

Comment: Thanks for reviewing :-) Please use one answer per question. Also note: having an answer or us finding the questions useful does not make them about notable claims :-)

Comment: @Sklivvz: You mean one question per answer?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant

Comment: The first two lack evidence of a notable claim, can you add it? The third appears to be a made up claim.

Comment: @Sklivvz: I'll try.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the "Does house cleaning counts as exercise should stay. A simple google of "house chores exercise" gives planty of examples for this claim.

Comment: Can you add some examples to the question then? The closest thing that I can find is the Daily Mail, but it also says " housework isn't a good form of cardiovascular exercise", which invalidates the claim imo.

Comment: I will, I dont have time right now, maybe later today or in the next few weeks.

Answer (score 0):

The exploding laptop battary question is perfectly fine. It has an example of notability (the xkcd comic) and this claim can be found all over the internet (google "exploding laptop battary").

Comment: Besides the XKCD comic, all the other linked examples actually state that a Li battery will *not* explode. The video shows people *not* exploding LiPo batteries etc. Your google search does not show examples of people claiming that a battery can be *exploded* (meaning: used as an explosive).

Comment: A. I didn't actualy view the google results, just saw their titles. B. I think that xkcd is a noteble source by its own, and if all other sources say that it's impossible, then they should be sources in an answer.